# Web scraping finviz for fundamental data on marketcap

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm trying to scrape finviz(https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl) for marketcap in the fundamental table but couldn't for the life of me locate the table or the class with beautiful soup. It seems that every time I use soup.find_all() it works for 'div', 'td', 'table' etc. but it returns an empty list when I try to add a class like {'class':'snapshot-td2'}. Does anyone know how I may fix this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4

def parseMarketCap():
    response = requests.get("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl")
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    table = soup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})
    print(table)
```

I also tried the following for the table, but no luck as well:

```
table = soup.find_all('table', {'class': "snapshot-table2"})
```

[inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdMo5.png)

[fundamental table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xQvi.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need an user-agent header, then you can use `-soup-contains:` to target the preceding `td` by its text then move to the desired value field:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('td:-soup-contains("Market Cap")').find_next('b').text)
```

Answer (score 1):

as QHarr suggest that you to add `user-agent` for proper response

```
response = requests.get("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl",headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
content_table = soup.find('table', {'class':'snapshot-table2'})
tabel_rows = content_table.find_all('tr')
market_cap = tabel_rows[1].find_all('td')[1].text

print(market_cap)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use User-Agent for your request like this:

```
user_agent = {'User Agent':'YOUR_USER_AGENT'}
r = requests.get('YOURURL', headers=user_agent)
...
```